# composer - your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install this lib: https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/

So here is my current `composer.json` file

```
...
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "anlutro/l4-settings": "^0.7.3",
    "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^1.11",
    "berkayk/onesignal-laravel": "^1.0",
    "chapeupreto/sinesp": "^1.5",
    "crockett/csv-seeder": "^1.1",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.5",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "kreait/firebase-php": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "malhal/laravel-geographical": "^1.0",
    "noh4ck/graphiql": "^1.0",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0",
    "rebing/graphql-laravel": "^1.14",
    "s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver": "^2.0",
    "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^2.0",
    "spatie/laravel-tags": "^2.0",
    "tightenco/ziggy": "^0.6.7",
    "total-voice/php-client": "1.*",
    "tucker-eric/eloquentfilter": "^1.4",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "zizaco/entrust": "^1.9"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
...
```

So I tried to run

```
composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets
```

But it shows errors

```
root@3bb47882f6a6:/var/www# composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets
Using version ^1.3 for beyondcode/laravel-websockets
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for beyondcode/laravel-websockets ^1.3 -> satisfiable by beyondcode/laravel-websockets[1.3.0].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.6.39
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- beyondcode/laravel-websockets 1.3.0 requires illuminate/broadcasting 5.7.* || 5.8.* || ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev], illuminate/broadcasting[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev, v5.6.39].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.8.x-dev, v5.6.39].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v5.6.39].
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- don't install illuminate/broadcasting v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.6.39, required as 5.6.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.39].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
root@3bb47882f6a6:/var/www#
```

What exactly mean these messages? How can I solve it?

Comment: _beyondcode/laravel-websockets 1.3.0 requires illuminate/broadcasting 5.7.* || 5.8.* || ^6.0_ This line is saying it won't work with Laravel < v5.7, based on a package dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this report you can see the following line, which means `laravel-websockets` required `illuminate/broadcasting` 5.7, 5.8 or 6.0+. It also gives you ALL version of `laravel/framework` that can satisfy this requirement (5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev):

```
- beyondcode/laravel-websockets 1.3.0 requires illuminate/broadcasting 5.7.* || 5.8.* || ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev], illuminate/broadcasting[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0].
```

In your composer file, we can see this line, which means you only allow `5.6.x` versions for Laravel in your project:

```
// require  
"laravel/framework": "5.6.*"
```

Composer is simply telling you that you cannot use `laravel-websockets` with Laravel 5.6

---

Here's the report reworded:

> Trying to install **laravel-websockets** 1.3.0
>
> Checking dependencies…
>   **laravel-websockets** 1.3.0 requires **illuminate/broadcasting** 5.7, 5.8 or 6.0+
>   But **illuminate/broadcasting** is already installed in another version
>
> Who required this illuminate/broadcasting version?
>   **laravel/framework** did it.
>
> Does it have any version where its **illuminate/broadcasting** requirement fits mine?
>   Yes, here they are: 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev
>
> Can I upgrade **laravel/framework** to one of this versions?
>   Checking requirements…
>   Nope, **laravel/framework** cannot go further than 5.6.x
>
> Failure